# Does Combined SE flair takes more time to update than Individual Sites Flair?

Tags: discussion, flair, combined-flair

Is it just me or Does Combined SE flair takes more time to update than Individual Sites Flair?

I have noticed that all my Individual sites flair are up-to-date almost all the time; but whenever I see my Combined Flair, it's not updated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, combined flair is slower to update than per site flair.  This is explicitly stated on your flair page:

https://stackexchange.com/users/YOUR_ID/YOUR-NAME?tab=flair

at the bottom it says,

> (please note that only sites where you have more than 200 reputation
> will appear, and that flair is only updated once every 24-36 hours.)

Comment: That message is also stated for per-site flairs.

Answer (score 2):

No, that's probably by design.

Per-site flair is provided by the site itself. For example, my Physics.SE flair has a URL `http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/flair/7433.png`. Note that the host is `physics.stackexchange.com`, not `stackexchange.com`.

On the other hand, my combined flair is `https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1212053.png`. The host is `stackexchange.com`

All SE sites cache inter-site data. For example, your rep and badges [here](https://stackexchange.com/users/1338926/rishabh-poddar?tab=accounts) and on the accounts section [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/182466/rishabh-poddar?tab=summary) will be slightly outdated, that's by design. Since `stackexchange.com` provides the combined flair, it will naturally use the cached value. I *think* the caching is to reduce a bunch of database queries(to different databases) that would otherwise have to be done every time someone views your profile/combined flair/whatnot.

On the other hand, the per-site flair need not use cached data, and even if it does, it can afford to update the cache much more frequently than the cross-site update.

Comment: `[status-caching]`, eh?